# Parallelizing Python class functions

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I need to parallelize some internal function calls that I have in a class in a much larger homebuilt framework.  I've attempted both multiprocessing and threading (separately), and when testing the amount of time required, I noticed that execution of those functions takes longer now than it did previously.

Reading over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669160/python-multiprocessing-is-taking-much-longer-than-single-processing?lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584109/how-to-parallelize-a-for-in-python-inside-a-class), I realized that the issue is probably that I'm attempting to parallelize a class member function, and that I'm running into class instance issues with the subprocesses/threads.

I could move the function outside of the class definition, passing in required data structures, however the function in question is deeply coupled to other member functions.

My question is...do I need to move all member functions outside of the class definition to realize the speedup I require, or is my understanding of the problem flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my implementation at least, I created a worker thread that handled all threaded code.  That thread communicated to the main thread using a simple pipe.  Easy to implement, and none of the overhead of mpc.