# Parallel loop within class method invoking another class method

Tags: python, class, serialization, pickle, python-multiprocessing

This question is related to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584109/how-to-parallelize-a-for-in-python-inside-a-class) posts on SO, yet the solutions suggested therein do not seem to work for my case. In short, my problem can be illustrated by the following example. I have an `Algebra` class where by the method `triPower` I aim at computing the power of a trinomial, i.e. `(a+b+c)**n` for many `n` values with fixed `a, b, c`. To do so, I thought of creating a method `_triPower(a,b,c,n)` and pass it to my `pool.map()` function by `functools.partial(_triPower,...)` where I fix `a, b, c` and leave `n` as the only parameter, since I am working in Python 2.7 and `map` from the `multiprocessing` module wants only one argument function (see otherwise [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)). The code is the following:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import functools as fntls
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.pool as mppl

# A couple of classes introduced to allow multiple processes to have their own daemons (parallelization)
class NoDaemonProcess(mp.Process):
   # make 'daemon' attribute always return False
   def _get_daemon(self):
      return False
   def _set_daemon(self, value):
      pass
   daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)

# We sub-class multiprocessing.pool.Pool instead of multiprocessing.Pool
# because the latter is only a wrapper function, not a proper class.
class MyPool(mppl.Pool):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

# Sample class where I want a method to run a parallel loop
class Algebra(object):
    def __init__(self,offset):
        self.offset = offset

    def trinomial(self,a,b,c):
        return a+b+c

    def _triPower(self,a,b,c,n):
    """This is the method that I want to run in parallel from the next method"""
        return self.offset + self.trinomial(a,b,c)**n

    def triPower(self,n):
        pls = MyPool(4)
        vals = pls.map(fntls.partial(self._triPower,a=1.,b=0.,c=1.),n)
        print vals

# Testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = Algebra(0.)
    A.triPower(np.arange(0.,10.,0.01))
```

The above does not work and produces (as expected from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function)) the error:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Hence, following the same post, I tried to define `_triPower` as a global function i.e.

```
def _triPower(alg,a,b,c,n):
"""This is the method that I want to run in parallel from the next method"""
    return alg.trinomial(a,b,c)**n
```

and then editing `Algebra.triPower(...)` according to:

```
    def triPower(self,n):
    pls = MyPool(4)
    vals = pls.map(fntls.partial(_triPower, alg=self, a=1., b=0., c=1.), n)
    print vals
```

and this latter instead gives some weird TypeError like:

```
TypeError: _triPower() got multiple values for keyword argument 'alg'
```

On the other hand the suggestion to try to make the methods serializable by [VeryPicklableObject](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/pynet/blob/master/process/VeryPicklableObject.py) as in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584109/how-to-parallelize-a-for-in-python-inside-a-class) seems also not to work and this package appears dead by now (as of 05/2019). So what am I doing wrong and how can I make my computation run in parallel?

Comment: In the "partial" call use simple position args like "self, 1., 0., 1." instead of keyword args.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, it solved the issue. I would however like to understand why it is like that and the `self` variable is not recognized. Also what if the variable that I want to vectorize/parallelize for is not `n` but any others with position not at the end of the list of input arguments of  `_triPower(alg,a,b,c,n)`, i.e. say for example `b`? I don't want to rewrite `_triPower` for any possible ordered configuration of inputs.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) show functional equivalent Python code for `partial`. The function returned by `partial` first applies given positional arguments at creation (none in your code), then pos. args. at call (here `n` only, which is applied to `alg` parameter). Then keyword arguments from call or creation. As there is also a keyword argument for `alg`, the error occurs. A solution can be instead of `partial` to pack all parameters into a tuple and use that as single argument to `_triPower`.